# why does XML sitemap on a sharepoint online website gets downloaded?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

The XML sitemap of the website in sharepoint online (office 365) always get downloaded.Can anyone tell me what could be the reason behind it and most important how to resolve it? Please help

Thanks,

Avy

Comment: When does it get downloaded?

Comment: it always get downloaded.

Comment: i was searching for any other sharepoint online website and i got these two examples. here same thing happens.the xml sitemap gets downloaded. http://www.councilofhealthcarescience.ac.uk/
http://www.pharmacyschoolscouncil.ac.uk/